# Nearest neighbours with a subset structure

Tags: nearest-neighbors

I have a set of points of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is organised in subsets:
$$
\cup_{0\leq i<N} \left\{ P_i^j \in \mathbb{R}^2, 0\leq j<M \right\}
$$
For all $(i,j)$, I want to find $P_k^l$ **in another subset (with $k\not= i$)** so that $d(P_k^l,P_i^j)$ is minimal. And "of course" (*), many points with $k=i$ are in general much closer to $P_i^j$ than points with $k\not=i$ (**).

Does that evoke any well known variant of nearest neighbour search problems?

If I use a standard R-tree approach, the leaves of search tree will be full of useless $P_i^l$ points, for which a costly distance calculation will be performed, and I will then have to filter them out. Of course this shouldn't alter the logarithmic cost in $O(\log(NM))$ if leaf size is appropriate, but I expect the constant to be much larger than with a tailored algorithm. Before deciding whether to code my own implementation, I would like to make sure that there aren't classical algorithms that would handle this case efficiently.

Notes: $N$ is of order 10, while $M$ of order $10^3$ to $10^4$. I'm using python, currently with scikit learn's nearest neighbour search.
(*) Not because it's natural, just because else there wouldn't be a reason to look for a variant algorithm. (**) Estimate is that about 40 points $P_i^l$ will in general be closer to $P_i^j$ than any $P_{k\not=i}^m$ for usual meshing, and this number will increase linearly with mesh refinement. This is because points of a same set discretise a curve of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and the $N$ curves don't intersect or touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a separate R-tree for each subset. Your NN lookup is then *N log(M)*. If the number of falsely proximal points exceeds *N* then you might have a time savings versus a single R-tree customized to discriminate by subset. You can also parallelize across *N*.

Comment: Thanks @Richard. Do you mean: generate a R-tree for each subset $S_k$, then find $P_k^{l_k}$ nearest neighbour of $P_i^j$ for all $i\not=k$? Indeed that sounds good.

Comment: @JoceNoToPutinsWarInUkraine: that is what I mean. Please circle back if the performance isn't acceptable.